# servicestack restful discovery udp

Tags: udp, servicestack, restful-architecture, ws-discovery, self-hosting

in WCF, I can create a udp endpoint discovery to allow client finding the service without knowing the endpoint addresses.

Is there a similar approach using restful servicestack so that the client could discovered the end point address using some kind of discovery detection ?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply from the author of ServiceStack, I'd create a [feature request](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/6422197-endpoint-configuration-discovery)

Answer (score 2):

with the introduction of the [ServiceGateway](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-Gateway), there are now two options for Service Discovery.

[ServiceStack.Discovery.Consul](https://github.com/MacLeanElectrical/servicestack-discovery-consul)

[ServiceStack.Discovery.Redis](https://github.com/rsafier/ServiceStack.Discovery.Redis)